# Determine function from partial graph

Tags: polynomials

If

[image]

Must $g(x)=-3(x+1)(x-1)$? Can't it like change down below?

For example, can we do something like $-3(x+1)(x-1)=a(x+1)(x-1)(x-b)$ for $x\in[-1,1]$? Then we'd add a new root $b$, but the top part of the graph would still be the same. I wasnt able to go further tho, so not sure if it works.

Comment: two polynomials of degree $n$ have at most $n$ intersections, or they are the same polynomial. So, no, you cant have the equality of two sides for all $x \in [-1,1]$. but other than polynomials, there are infinitely many extensions beyond [-1,1], but not polynomials

Comment: The polynomial you suggest might have a graph that looks (slightly) different, even in the small interval shown on the graph. But as you don't say $g$ has to be continuous, you can of course make functions that are given by that polynomial on the interval shown, but has any value you'd like at e.g. $4$. As the value at that point can be *anything*, e.g. $5$, "down below" isn't really fitting, it's something that is happening (in my example) to the right and *above* the shown. Similarly "the top part of the graph" is also not good.